# Can't Get Wordpress Settings Link To Work

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to build my first Wordpress plugin and it's giving me a ~LOT~ of grief.

I've got a plugin template I'm using, and I'm following [THIS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-wordpress-plugin-part-1) tutorial to turn it into something I can use.

The tutorial says to put a function in [insert plugin name]-admin.php to make 'settings' appear near the plugin on the plugins.php page.

This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image: settings]
<sub>(source: [scotch.io](https://cask.scotch.io/2015/08/menu_links_added.jpg))</sub>

The thing is, I have tried inserting the function and I just can't get this 'settings' link to appear.

The code the tutorial says to use is this:

```
public function add_action_links( $links ) {

 $settings_link = array( '<a href="' . admin_url( 'options-general.php?page=' . $this->plugin_name ) . '">' . __('Settings', $this->plugin_name) . '</a>', );
return array_merge( $settings_link, $links );
}
```

I've tried using this--and similar snippets that I've found on other sites after googling--and none of them work. I know that page= is supposed to link to the page URL, I'm not entirely sure what mine is (is it the plugin slug?). Anyway, I'm currently using the plugin slug after 'page='

If anybody here could help me out with this, it would be greatly appreciated. I know the tutorial I'm using was sloppily written because I have managed to find mistakes in it that were causing errors, and I'm relatively new to PHP and totally new to Wordpress plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also add the beloning add_filter?

Like here:

```
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'my_plugin_action_links' );

function my_plugin_action_links( $links ) {
   $links[] = '<a href="'. esc_url( get_admin_url(null, 'options-general.php?page=gpaisr') ) .'">Settings</a>';
   $links[] = '<a href="http://wp-buddy.com" target="_blank">More plugins by WP-Buddy</a>';
   return $links;
}
```

Also see:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/plugin_action_links_(plugin_file_name)

Comment: Thanks.

Yes, I've tried adding add_filter but it seems to cause my entire theme to not work when the plugin is activated. Wordpress just doesn't load. Should I maybe be doing this on a different .php file?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the add_filter for action links is in my class-[insert plugin name].php file. It does add the action links for 'deactivate' and 'visit site'. I'm wondering if the reason the settings page isn't showing up is because I haven't created it?